# Regex for multiple lines separated with "return" and multiple unnecessary spaces

Tags: python, regex

I was trying to parse together a script for a movie into a dataset containing two columns 'speaker_name' and 'line_spoken'. I don't have any issue with the Python part of the problem but parsing the script is the problem.

The schema of the script goes like this:

[image: Schema of Script]

Now, this, if copied and pasted into a .txt file is something like this:

```
ARTHUR

Yeah. I mean, that's just--

SOCIAL WORKER

Does my reading it upset you?

He leans in.

ARTHUR

No. I just,-- some of it's

personal. You know?

SOCIAL WORKER

I understand. I just want to make

sure you're keeping up with it.

She slides his journal back to him. He holds it in his lap.
```

In the above case, the regex filtering should return the speaker name and the dialogue and not what is happening in actions like the last line: "slides his journal back". The dialogues often exceed more than two lines so please do not provide hard-coded solutions for 2 lines only. I think I am thinking about this problem in just one direction, some other method to filter can also work.

I have worked with scripts that are colon-separated and I don't have any problem parsing those. But in this case, I am getting no specific endpoints to end the search at. It would be a great help if the answer you give has 2 groups, one with name, the other with the dialogue. Like in the case of colon-separated, my regex was:

```
pattern = r'(^[a-zA-z]+):(.+)'
```

Also, if possible, please try and explain why you used that certain regex. It will be a learning experience for me.

Comment: In your original, dialogues and actions are differentiated with spacing. But you seem to have eliminated leading spacing from your text. That basically erases the distinction between dialogue and action. A human reader can (mostly) recreate the difference by understanding the text; however, that's a semantic analysis which is far outside of the possibilities of a strictly lexical tool like a regular expression. I would think that your best strategy is to start by trying not to lose essential information when turning the script into a text file.

Comment: The script file that I have is in the form of a pdf, so I will have to paste it into a new file I think. Or is there some way to directly use a pdf file as a source and then build on top of that? Or I might have to get another version of the same script that is not in pdf format and contains the spaces before the lines, that provide important information.

Comment: PDF is intended to preserve appearance, not semantics. Sometimes it is possible to extract information more or less intact, but there are no guarantees. You'll have to experiment with the conversion tools you have access to. If you can find the version of the script from which the PDF was made, you might find it easier to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use https://www.onlineocr.net/ co convert pdf to text,

It shows immediately the outcome, where names and on the same line with dialogs,
which could allow for a simple processing

```
   ARTHUR Yeah. I mean, that's just--
   SOCIAL WORKER Does my reading it upset you?
   He leans in.  
   ARTHUR No. I just,-- some of its personal. You know me ?  
   SOCIAL WORKER I understand. I just want to make sure you're keeping up with it.  

   She slides his journal back to him. He holds it in his lap.
```

Not sure will it work for longer dialogs.

Another solution is to extract data from the text file that you can download by clicking the "download output file" link [image: snapshot]. That file is formatted differently. In that file
10 leading spaces will indicate the dialog, and 5 leading spaces the name - a the least for you sample screenshot
The regex is

```
r"          (.+)(\n(     [^ ].+\n)+)"
```

https://regex101.com/r/FQk8uH/1

it puts in group 1 whatever starts with ten spaces and  whatever starts with at the exactly five space into the second :
the subexpression "    [^ ].+\n" denotes a line where the first five symbols are spaces, the sixth symbol is anything but space, and the rest of symbols until the end of line are arbitrary. Since dialogs tend to be multiline that expression is followed with another plus.

You will have to delete extra white space from dialogue with additional code and/or regex.

If the amount of spaces varies a bit (say 4-6 and 7 - 14 respectively) but has distinct section the regex needs to be adjusted by using variable repetition operator (curly braces  `{4, 6}`) or optional spaces  `?`.

```
r" {7, 14}(.+)(\n( {4-6}[^ ].+\n)+)"
```

The last idea is to use preexisting list of names in play to match them e.g. `(SOCIAL WORKER|JOHN|MARY|ARTUR)`. The https://www.onlineocr.net/ website still could be used to help spot and delete actions

Comment: Hi, thank you for your solution. But I didn't get the second part of your solution. What link did you mean when you said: "alternatively download from a link"? I tried to apply your solution to another version of the script where spaces defined the schema, but unfortunately, the spacing was not consistent. It was recognizing some of the lines but not all. If you do get a source that has consistent spacing, like the 5 and 10 spaced one you were talking about, do let me know about it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If that script puts variable yet still nonoverlapping ranges for name and dialogue say 8 - 14 vs 3 - 6 that regex can be adjusted with variable repetition `" {8, 14}"` `" {3, 6}"` or optional symbols `"    ? ? ?". Otherwise, if it is completely irregular, do not use my method

Comment: I am accepting your answer as the one cuz this is the one that has come closest to solving the problem. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, you can use `DOTALL`:

```
re_pattern = re.compile(r'(\b[A-Z ]{3,}(?=\n))\n*(.*?)\n*(?=\b[A-Z ]{3,}\n|$)', re.DOTALL)
print(re.findall(re_pattern, mystr))
```

- `\b[A-Z ]{3,}(?=\n)` matches speaker name.

  - `\b` matches a word boundary
  - `[A-Z ]{3,}` matches three or more upper case letters or spaces. (this means this regex won't recognize speaker names with less than three characters. I did this to avoid false positives in special cases but you might wanna change it. Also check what kind of characters might occur in speaker name (dots, minus, lower case...))
  - `(?=\n)` is a lookahead insuring the speaker name is directly followed by a new line (avoids false positive if a similar expression appears in a spoken line)
- `\n*` matches newlines
- `(.*?)` matches everything (including new lines thanks to DOTALL) until the next part of the expression (`?` makes it lazy instead of greedy)
- `\n*` matches newlines
- `(?=\b[A-Z ]{3,}\n|$)` is a lookahead i.e. a non capturing expression insuring the following part is either a speaker name or the end of your string

Output:

```
[('ARTHUR', "Yeah. I mean, that's just--"), ('SOCIAL WORKER', 'Does my reading it upset you?\n\nHe leans in.'), ('ARTHUR', "No. I just,-- some of it's\n\npersonal. You know?"), ('SOCIAL WORKER', "I understand. I just want to make\n\nsure you're keeping up with it.\n\nShe slides his journal back to him. He holds it in his lap.")]
```

You'll have to adjust formatting if you want to remove actions from the result though.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Tranbi. I'll convert it into word format and then let you know about the updated schema. The lookahead in your answer was what I needed. I'll let you know soon. Thanks a lot for helping out.

Comment: Glad I could be of any help! Looking at the expression again I noticed it would be wiser to check that the speaker name is directly followed by a new line. So I edited my answer accordingly

Comment: I have converted the pdf to a docx file. I understand that we can extract the contents of a docx file but I don't know how to incorporate regex to do that since we need to use the formatting as the main filtering factor. I would appreciate help in that if possible. If out of scope of the current title, I can open another topic.

Comment: Have you tried with [python-docx](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)? If you encounter trouble importing text from docx, I'd suggest opening a new topic. Once you successfully imported the content of your docx, just update the current question.